# Arrange associative array in Descending order base on the key => value

Tags: php

Do you know how to order this array in Descending order basing on the time_sent value?

I've been using some ksort or usort, but still it fails.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [time_sent] => 1343805651
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [time_sent] => 1343805328
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [time_sent] => 1343890728
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [time_sent] => 1343743340
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [time_sent] => 1343726917
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [time_sent] => 1343893364
        )

)
```

Comment: What "fails"? There's a ton of sample code for `usort` both in the manual and on SO. What have you tried and what is the problem?

Comment: This is my answer usort($result, create_function('$a,$b', 'return $b["time_sent"] - $a["time_sent"];')); 
 :-P !

Answer (score 1):

try multisort :

```
 array_multisort($array, SORT_DESC);
```